# Default copy count when using quick print in Office 2010

Tags: printing, microsoft-office-2010

So I have one machine in our organization that wants to print 65 pages every time you use quick print. This is with old and new documents. This is with documents created locally or by other people. Even when you go to File > Print, the copy count is set to 65.

Has anyone had this happen to them and do they know where this setting is controlled? I'd hate to re-image the machine for something so trivial, but it is wasting a bunch of paper.

Comment: Depending on your OS you might find that setting under Printing Preferences, in Printers, in Control Panel. Does it try to print 65 pages if you print from Notepad too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the driver's default copy count has been set to 65.

Go to printer Properties from Printers & Faxes. First click the Advanced tab and then the Printing Defaults button, set the number of copies to 1, and Click OK. Next, click the General tab, the Printing Preferences button and set the copy count there as well, if necessary.

Comment: We've re-imaged since then, but this sounds like a great solution.